# Text color doesn't change

Tags: html, css, text, colors, styling

I'm a total beginner at coding and my first problem I can't figure out is that when I use CSS sheet as a change of h1 and h3 color it basically doesn't change.

I tried to set a `<h1>` text color in CSS sheet and it didn't change.

```css
body {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

h1 {
  color: blue;
}

h3 {
  color: blue;
}

hr {
  border-color: grey;
  border-style: none;
  border-top-style: dotted;
  border-width: 5px;
  width: 5%;
}
```

```html
<h1>H1</h1>
<hr/>
<h3>H3</h3>
```

---

That's my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Kacper's Personal Site </title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/styles.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
```

for background color it works properly.

Comment: Does the Background-color of the Body changes? Let's see if the file is imported unto your HTML file correctly.

Comment: I made a snippet. Your CSS works. Did you place it in `<style></style>` tags?

Comment: You need to link your file with CSS in HTML `<head></head>` using `<link type="text/css" href="path_to_your_css_file.css">` or add your CSS directly to `<style></style>` in your HTML. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style

Comment: In HTML i got my CSS linked as: `    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Kacper's Personal Site </title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/styles.css'>` and background color works properly

Comment: hit the run snippet button below your question and you see its working just fine! you probably have problem in placing your style files

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a separate file of CSS then link your CSS file to an HTML file like `<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></head>`,see here https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-link-css-to-html/

Answer (score 0):

When you use a separate CSS file, you need to link that CSS file to the html document.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>H1</h1>
<hr/>
<h3>H3</h3>
    </body>
    </html>
```